# Centering text in a progress bar

Tags: html, css

I would like the label in the progress bar centered in the grey bar (100%) and not centered in the green bar.

Here is what I tried so far:

```css
#progressbar {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding: 3px;
}

#progressbar>div {
  background-color: #B3D8A9;
  height: 20px;
}

.progress-label {
  font-size: .9em;
  positsion: absolute;

}
```

```html
<div id="progressbar">
   <div style="width:75%;">
      <p class="progress-label"><strong>75%</strong></p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You might consider using the [<progress> element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/progress)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you mistake here

```
positsion: absolute;
```

it should be **position: absolute**

After then if you want to make label center to grey bar then you needs to add **position: relative** at **#progressbar**

```css
#progressbar {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    padding: 3px;
    position: relative;
}

#progressbar>div {
    background-color: #B3D8A9;
    height: 20px;
}

.progress-label {
    font-size: .9em;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="progressbar">
   <div style="width:75%;">
      <p class="progress-label"><strong>75%</strong></p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If that's the fix, you should vote to close as such (typo error).

Comment: @Rob You can see his question and his code which is posted. label isn't in center of grey box.

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: relative` for `#progressbar`

```css
#progressbar {
    background-color: lightgrey;
    padding: 3px;
    position:relative;
}

#progressbar>div {
    background-color: #B3D8A9;
    height: 20px;
}

.progress-label {
    font-size: .9em;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:50%;
    transform:translateX(-50%);

}
```

```html
<div id="progressbar">
   <div style="width:75%;">
      <p class="progress-label"><strong>75%</strong></p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not nest the text inside the 'inner' progress bar anyway:

```css
#progress-bar
{
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  height: 30px;
  
  background-color: gray;
}

#progress, #progress-percentage {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#progress-percentage {
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;
  line-height: 30px;
}

#progress {
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: green;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="progress-bar">
  <div id="progress-percentage">progress: 100%</div>
  <div id="progress"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful to fix your issue.

```css
#progressbar {
  position: relative; 
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding: 3px;
}

#progressbar>div {
  background-color: #B3D8A9;
  height: 20px;
}

.progress-label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: .9em;
  margin: 0;
  height: 26px;
}
```

```html
<div id="progressbar">
   <div style="width:75%;">
     <p class="progress-label"><strong>75%</strong></p>
   </div>
</div>
```